# Facebook share dialog web doesn't work on iOS in-app browser

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins, in-app

My website has a social dialog web which works on most browsers and even Facebook in-app browser on Android device but not iOS.  The header of the social dialog (with Cancel on left and Post on right) is missing when displayed on Facebook in-app browser.  The flow of accessing my website as follow:

1. A shared link (external link pointing to my website) is clicked on Facebook app on iOS device.
2. My website is displayed on Facebook in-app browser (which I hate it so much but can't help).
3. Open the following social dialog and the header of the dialog is missing.

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=1520072421556747&display=popup&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sharefer.me%2Fpromotion%2F52956d269cd90fb5399d5ced%2Fuser1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sharefer.me%2Fshared%2F52956d269cd90fb5399d5ced%2Fuser1

Is anyone facing the same problem?  Must I create the shared dialog for iOS instead of web to solve this problem but Android has no problem at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? Having the same problem...